# Big Query - Convert a int column into float

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I would like to convert a column called `lauder` from `int` to `float` in Big Query. My table is called `historical`. I have been able to use this SQL query

```
 SELECT *, CAST(lauder as float64) as temp 
FROM sandbox.dailydev.historical
```

The query works but the changes are not saved into the table. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to save them in a temporary table to use it later?

You can save it to a temporary table like below and then refer to "temp"

```
with temp as
( SELECT *, CAST(lauder as float64) 
FROM sandbox.dailydev.historical)
```

Comment: Thanks ! How to directly store it in the current table?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure if I got it. would you like to save the new data in the "historical" table?

Comment: @Pierre56, You need to alter your table and insert into the table - you can follow SKM's answer that given below

Answer (score 3):

If you use `SELECT *` you will scan the whole table and thus will be the cost. If table is small this shouldn't be a problem, but if it is big enough to be concern about cost  - below is another approach:

1. apply [ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#alter_table_add_column_statement) to add new column of needed data type
2. apply [UPDATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#update_statement) for new column

   UPDATE table
   SET new_column = CAST(old_column as float64)
   WHERE true

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is correct.  But tables columns in Big Query are immutable.  You need to run your query and save results to a new table with the modified column.

Click "More" > "Query settings", and in "Destination" select "Set a destination table for query results" and fill the table name. You can even select if you want to overwrite the existing table with generated one.

After these settings are set, just "Run" your query as usual.

[image: Snapshot 1]

[image: Snapshot 2]

Answer (score 1):

You can not change a columns data type in a table
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/manually-changing-schemas#changing_a_columns_data_type

What you can do is either:

1. Create a view to sit on top and handle the data type conversion
2. Create a new column and set the data type to float64 and insert values into it
3. Overwrite the table

Options 2 and 3 are outlined well including pros and cons in the link I shared above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **CREATE or REPLACE TABLE** to write the structural changes along with data into the same table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE sandbox.dailydev.historical
AS SELECT *, CAST(lauder as float64) as temp FROM sandbox.dailydev.historical;
```

> In this example, `historical` table will be restructured with an additional column `temp`.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases you can change column types:

```
CREATE TABLE mydataset.mytable(c1 INT64);
ALTER TABLE mydataset.mytable ALTER COLUMN c1 SET DATA TYPE NUMERIC;
```

Check conversion [rules](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conversion_rules).

And google [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas#change_a_columns_data_type).