# For Bigquery table schemas, how do I change a column's mode from NULLABLE to REQUIRED?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a table in BigQuery and want to change the mode of a column from NULLABLE to REQUIRED.

According to the Google documentation for modifying BigQuery table schemas the only way to do this goes as follows: "You can manually change a column's mode by exporting your table data to Cloud Storage, and then loading the data into a new table with a schema definition that specifies the correct mode for the column. You can also use the load job to overwrite the existing table." (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/manually-changing-schemas#changing_a_columns_mode).

I have 2 questions about that.

1. What does this last sentence "You can also use the load job to overwrite the existing table" mean? Does this mean I can somehow make this schema change in the existing table and don't actually have to make a new table?
2. I want to avoid creating a new table and just make schema changes to my existing table. **Is there a way to change the mode of a column from NULLABLE to REQUIRED in my existing table?** For other modifications like deleting a column from a table schema or changing a column's data type it is possible to use a query job for that (option 1 in the doc). Is there also a query job I can do to change a column's mode? BigQuery does not seem to support something like "ALTER TABLE [Table] ALTER COLUMN [Column] INTEGER NOT NULL".

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

1. Given the documentation no you will have to create a new table in that scenario.
2. There is no way to change the definition of a column (data type or mode)

What you could alternatively do is add a new column that has the new definition and update the column with the values from the old column.

See Mikhail's answer to this post:
[Big Query - Convert a int column into float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64460010/big-query-convert-a-int-column-into-float/64465325#64465325)

Answer (score 0):

The important part of the documentation you need to read is Modifying Table schemas, more precisely the section [Relaxing a column mode](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas#relaxing_a_columns_mode). In there you can see this two key lines:

- *Currently, the only supported modification you can make to a column's mode is changing it from REQUIRED to NULLABLE.*
- **Caution: Changing a REQUIRED column to NULLABLE cannot be undone.**

Meaning, there is no way to change a NULLABLE column to REQUIRED but you can change a REQUIRED column to NULLABLE.

I tried anyway to proceed with the change, all schema changes, as shown in the aforementioned official documentation can be done using bq update, calling table.patch method or with a client library. I described it more extensively in [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61080180/12852090). In any case, when modifying the column in the schema from NULLABLE to REQUIRED and trying to update, one is met with the error:

`BigQuery error in update operation: Provided Schema does not match Table <project-id>:<dataset-id>.<table-id>. Field <field-name> has changed mode from NULLABLE to REQUIRED`

Confirming this is not supported.

However, you can follow your workaround mentioned in your first question, i.e. loading the data overwriting the same named table.

Basically, the steps are:

1. Export to GCS
2. Load the data overwriting the same table

I performed a quick experiment to double-check it works properly.

1. I exported the data to a CSV file in GCS [using the UI](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exporting_table_data).
2. I overwrote the table following [Appending to or overwriting a table with CSV data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#appending_to_or_overwriting_a_table_with_csv_data). Basically I used the command:

```sh
bq load \
--source_format=CSV \
--replace \
--max_bad_records=3 \
<dataset-id>.<table-id> \
gs://<MyBucket>/<myexportedfile> \
<mymodifiedschemafile>
```

As a result I had the same table I had before but with the field changed from NULLABLE to REQUIRED, confirming this workaround works properly!