# How to convert the column type in a BigQuery SQL result from NULLABLE to REQUIRED?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Have already looked at [discussion on converting schema of a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64564552).

I have a different problem:

- Already have a table with some NULLABLE columns
- Cannot change that table's schema
- Will be running queries against that table
- I can ensure that the *results* will not contain nulls
- How do I get the resultset's column types to be REQUIRED (ie not NULLABLE)?

For example, say I have a table like so:

```
PhoneContactSummary
-------------------
contact_time: TIMESTAMP, REQUIRED
customer_id: string, NULLABLE
issue_code: string, NULLABLE
...
```

So let's say I wanted to count contacts for known customers (ie customer_id != NULL).

I would write this:

```
SELECT customer_id, COUNT(1) AS num_contacts
FROM PhoneContactSummary
WHERE customer_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY customer_id
```

This would produce a result with:

```
customer_id: string, NULLABLE
num_contacts: int64, REQUIRED
```

The question is: since I know customer_id is never null in the result, how do I convert the type to REQUIRED?

If it were a simple type conversion, I would use the `CAST(...)` operation.

Comment: When I've faced this problem in the past, I think I needed to create the table with the declarations I wanted and then to insert into it.  Perhaps this functionality has been added in since then.

Comment: You cannot add a REQUIRED column to an existing table schema. However, you can create a nested REQUIRED column as part of a new RECORD field. You need to re-create the table definitions and move your existing data to the new table.

Comment: But I am not creating a new table at all. I just want the column to be REQUIRED in the type system, so for example, when I do a save-as BQ Table, the schema doesn't have a nullable column.